# Выбрать ближайший элемент в массиве по Timestamp

Tags: массивы

Пожалуйста, подскажите. Есть массив:

```
var Times = [
  {'t':1535453166750,'descr':'Время 1'},
  {'t':1535441482000,'descr':'Время 2'},
  {'t':1535441482000,'descr':'Время 3'}
];
```

t = Время, в формате Unix Timestamp.

Как можно произвести выборку, чтобы передав параметр, например *t=1535453083250*, получить ближайшее или точное значение *descr*, если есть элемент, удовлетворяющий условие t>=элемент.t

Comment: Массив отсортирован?

Comment: Да, массив отсортирован (от меньшего к большому)

Comment: Пытался таким образом: 
var res = Times.find(c=>1535453083250 >= c.ts);
Но возвращается результат меньше, чем входной параметр.

Comment: Тогда просто идите по массиву и сравнивайте элементы с t, пока не дойдете до нужного.

Comment: В примере массив не отсортирован

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно пробежаться по массиву, подсчитать разницу `t - элемент.t` и вывести элемент с минимальной неотрицательной разницей

```js
var Times = [
  {'t':1535453166750,'descr':'Время 1'},
  {'t':1535441482000,'descr':'Время 2'},
  {'t':1535441482000,'descr':'Время 3'}
];

t=1535453083250;

function findNear(ATimes, AT) {
  var res = -1;
  var delta = -1;
  for (var i = 0; i < ATimes.length; i++) {
    const curDelta = AT - ATimes[i].t;
    if (curDelta === 0)  // нашли точное совпадение. Выходим
      return i;
    if (curDelta > 0 && (delta === -1 || curDelta < delta)) {
      res = i;
      delta = curDelta;
    }
  }
  return res;
}

console.log(Times[findNear(Times, t)].descr);
```

Если же массив отсортирован по возрастанию времени, до достаточно найти первую неотрицательную разницу

```js
function findNear(ATimes, AT) {
  for (var i = 0; i < ATimes.length; i++) {
    const delta = AT - ATimes[i].t;
    if (delta >= 0)
      return i;
  }
  return -1;
}
```

Comment: Можно по всем не бегать, достаточно до первого с неотрицательной разницей (в случае сортированного массива).

Comment: В вопросе масссив не отсортирован

Comment: Отсортирован по уменьшению t.

Comment: Автор  [утверждает](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/876651/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be-timestamp/876664#comment1423444_876651), что отсортирован по возрастанию

Comment: Поэтому я и уточнил, что необязательно подсчитывать разницу с каждым элементов.

Comment: Простите, пожалуйста. На самом деле массив - отсортирован, единственное в примере последовательность задал не по порядку. 

Спасибо, большое за помощь. Проверил, все действительно работает.

Comment: Если массив отсортирован, то да. А отсортирован ли он у автора -  неизвестно. Автор путается в показаниях

Comment: Для отсортированного подойдёт бинарный поиск